# SPP profile bluetooth iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, serial-port, spp

does anyone got a sample code of SPP communication ( serial over bluetooth ) for iOS ?
I'd need to communicate between my microchip pic and an iphone or iPod.

I know I need a approved apple bluetooth rs232<->BT dongle and I have some with a MFi contract too ;)

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For people like me who were looking at infos.

If you are not going to use Bluetooth LE devices with iOS and the associated corebluetooth,
you need a MFi licence and bluetooth module from a certified vendor.

Using those modules does not involve the corebluetooth but another thing.
Have a look at the EADemo [Demo on how to link to MFi device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079)
The linked bluetooth module will be accessible this way.

Comment: :Do you know how to transfer the contacts from iphone to bluetooth(MFi) device using Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP).

Comment: No sorry, I'm using bluetooth to transfer live data from sensors.

Comment: "> If you are not going to use Bluetooth LE devices with iOS" -- does that mean that an MFi license is NOT required for BLE device connections?

Comment: Rubistro: correct you do NOT need a MFI license to do BLE only devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. For small projects, research, development, etc., there are many companies that sell RS232 and USB to Bluetooth dongles. These are easy controllable via a simple and limited API. Here is an [example](http://www.bluegiga.com/eval_wt12). There are also similar chinese companies [here](http://www.avantwave.com/) or [here](http://www.bluegiga.com/show_news?id=21853935)
   If you want iPhone connectivity it is just a matter of getting hold of a couple of MFi co-processors and soldering them on to the dev board. The firmware should alreadyhandle iOS connections. See [**this**](http://www.bluegiga.com/show_news?id=21853935).
2. If you have more serious intentions, like making your own hardware, you need to look at:

   - Bluetooth chips. [Here](http://www.csr.com/) is the website of a major vendor specialized in BT chips. You can also try Texas Instruments, Microchip, etc.
   - [MFi authentication co-processors](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am under MFi contract but was in need of informations and source example and I found.