# iOS support Bluetooth SPP

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I know this question may be little known stuff, but all the forums messages I've seen are slightly older than 2 yrs.
So can I re-iterate asking this question that can iOS support Bluetooth SPP (Classic/Smart)?

Also two more questions running in my mind are, in some of the queries I've seen that Laird (BT800 and BL600 series) dongles shall support SPP and lintech.de also got a Bluetooth adapter which shall support SPP.

Can somebody please confirm if the Bluetooth SPP (client) on iOS been driven to a HID Keyboard events in Server side (Linux/Any target OS).?

Comment: It seems it did not change since [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663822/spp-profile-bluetooth-ios). If you not do it over Bluetooth LE then you need to join the Apple MFI program.

Comment: @rckoenes, thanks for the prompt response appreciate that...but it seems so disappointing,...., its almost 3 yrs and from iOS side no update to support,Is there any other approach to have the Keyboard events (HID) when a trigger done in iOS (App).We thought SPP (BLE) would be a choice, but now looks like even that is ruled out.

Comment: Well Apple has restricted the user of bluetooth to LE only (4.0) on newer devices. You can get more acces but you will have to join the MFI program. Not sure what is possible with LE, because other then iBeacons I've not done any other work with bluetooth.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you....I've no idea on this iBeacons, I will look into it though..could you please let me know if my idea is feasible or not with iOS platform - An iOS App which generates a key stroke trigger sends the command via Bluetooth LE to a non iOS device (probably a BT dongle which supports BLE) and takes it a HID (Key event)?Does this sounds something technically feasible.?