# Can I use RFCOMM bluetooth protocol to share data between an iOS device and another device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, rfcomm

Is there any class or framework in iOS (swift or objective-c)that can handle RFCOMM bluetooth protocol as `BluetoothAdapter` in Android

Comment: No,  RFComm is a legacy profile and is not available to apps on iOS.  Only the BLE GATT profile is available.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, it is possible to use profiles based on RFCOMM, for example SPP or any other custom RFCOMM based profile.

BUT: The peer device needs an Apple MFI chip, must be certified by Apple and implement the iAP protocol.

See [SPP profile bluetooth iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663822/spp-profile-bluetooth-ios)